# get TopN of all groups after group by using Spark DataFrame

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark SQL DataFrame:

```
user1 item1 rating1
user1 item2 rating2
user1 item3 rating3
user2 item1 rating4
...
```

How to group by user and then return `TopN` items from every group using Scala?

Similarity code using Python:

```
df.groupby("user").apply(the_func_get_TopN)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `rank` window function as follows

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{rank, desc}

val n: Int = ???

// Window definition
val w = Window.partitionBy($"user").orderBy(desc("rating"))

// Filter
df.withColumn("rank", rank.over(w)).where($"rank" <= n)
```

If you don't care about ties then you can replace `rank` with `row_number`