# How to select specific rows according to the other column?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am a quite new to Spark dataset SQL.

Below is my dataset table consisting of multiple columns as below.

```
+---+--------+--------+-----------+---------+---------+--------------------+--------+----------+----------+
|avg|badCount|effectID|globalCount|goodCount|paramType|               ratio|    tool|  toolName|totalCount|
+---+--------+--------+-----------+---------+---------+--------------------+--------+----------+----------+
|0.0|    32.0|     0.0|       84.0|     52.0|      CAT| 0.38095238095238093|    tool|  litho_c3|    1001.0|
|0.0|     0.0|     0.0|       85.0|     85.0|      CAT|                 0.0|    tool|  litho_c1|    1001.0|
|0.0|     0.0|     0.0|       75.0|     75.0|      CAT|                 0.0|    tool|  litho_c7|    1001.0|
|0.0|     0.0|     0.0|       97.0|     97.0|      CAT|                 0.0|    tool|  litho_c6|    1001.0|
|0.0|     0.0|     0.0|       86.0|     86.0|      CAT|                 0.0|    tool| litho_c10|    1001.0|
|0.0|     0.0|     0.0|       95.0|     95.0|      CAT|                 0.0|    tool|  litho_c8|    1001.0|
|0.0|     0.0|     0.0|       79.0|     79.0|      CAT|                 0.0|    tool|  litho_c9|    1001.0|
|0.0|     0.0|     0.0|       65.0|     65.0|      CAT|                 0.0|    tool|  litho_c2|    1001.0|
|0.0|     0.0|     0.0|       87.0|     87.0|      CAT|                 0.0|    tool| litho_c12|    1001.0|
|0.0|     0.0|     0.0|       82.0|     82.0|      CAT|                 0.0|    tool|  litho_c4|    1001.0|
|0.0|     0.0|     0.0|       79.0|     79.0|      CAT|                 0.0|    tool|  litho_c5|    1001.0|
|0.0|     0.0|     0.0|       87.0|     87.0|      CAT|                 0.0|    tool| litho_c11|    1001.0|
|0.0|    32.0|     0.0|     1001.0|    969.0|      CAT| 0.03196803196803197|  recipe|r_ 15 _1.1|    1001.0|
|0.0|    12.0|     0.0|      335.0|    323.0|      CAT| 0.03582089552238806|operator|     c2_o3|    1001.0|
|0.0|    10.0|     0.0|      328.0|    318.0|      CAT| 0.03048780487804878|operator|     c1_o3|    1001.0|
|0.0|    10.0|     0.0|      338.0|    328.0|      CAT|0.029585798816568046|operator|     c3_o3|    1001.0|
|0.0|    32.0|     0.0|      248.0|    216.0|      CAT| 0.12903225806451613|    mask|    mask_3|    1001.0|
|0.0|     0.0|     0.0|      263.0|    263.0|      CAT|                 0.0|    mask|    mask_2|    1001.0|
|0.0|     0.0|     0.0|      245.0|    245.0|      CAT|                 0.0|    mask|    mask_4|    1001.0|
|0.0|     0.0|     0.0|      245.0|    245.0|      CAT|                 0.0|    mask|    mask_1|    1001.0|
+---+--------+--------+-----------+---------+---------+--------------------+--------+----------+----------+
```

What I want to do is to extract two rows which has the highest ratio value according to the column tool.

For example, in the `operator` tool, the highest ratio value are `0.03582089552238806` and `0.03048780487804878`. Therefore I want to extract below two rows out of three rows in the `operator` tool.

```
|0.0|    12.0|     0.0|      335.0|    323.0|      CAT| 0.03582089552238806|operator|     c2_o3|    1001.0|
|0.0|    10.0|     0.0|      328.0|    318.0|      CAT| 0.03048780487804878|operator|     c1_o3|    1001.0|
```

In this way, the final table looks like as below.

```
+---+--------+--------+-----------+---------+---------+--------------------+--------+----------+----------+
|avg|badCount|effectID|globalCount|goodCount|paramType|               ratio|    tool|  toolName|totalCount|
+---+--------+--------+-----------+---------+---------+--------------------+--------+----------+----------+
|0.0|    32.0|     0.0|       84.0|     52.0|      CAT| 0.38095238095238093|    tool|  litho_c3|    1001.0|
|0.0|     0.0|     0.0|       85.0|     85.0|      CAT|                 0.0|    tool|  litho_c1|    1001.0|
|0.0|    32.0|     0.0|     1001.0|    969.0|      CAT| 0.03196803196803197|  recipe|r_ 15 _1.1|    1001.0|
|0.0|    12.0|     0.0|      335.0|    323.0|      CAT| 0.03582089552238806|operator|     c2_o3|    1001.0|
|0.0|    10.0|     0.0|      328.0|    318.0|      CAT| 0.03048780487804878|operator|     c1_o3|    1001.0|
|0.0|    32.0|     0.0|      248.0|    216.0|      CAT| 0.12903225806451613|    mask|    mask_3|    1001.0|
|0.0|     0.0|     0.0|      263.0|    263.0|      CAT|                 0.0|    mask|    mask_2|    1001.0|
```

Note that the `recipe` tool has the only one row, so it extracts just one row.

How to achieve my issue using the Spark dataset?

Comment: What version of Spark are you using?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655467/get-topn-of-all-groups-after-group-by-using-spark-dataframe

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am using 2.3.0 version.